# How to make the multirow middle?

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

My table below context circle `Number` is not located centre.

I am using: `\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Number}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Accuracy (\%)}}\\`

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
    %   \addlinespace[1.2ex]
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Number}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}}      & {\textbf{BB}}      & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule     
    Number & AA & BB & CC\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Just try using `\multirow{2.4}` instead of `\multirow{2}`

Comment: @antshar. Thanks, it works. What is the reason using `2.4` instead of `2`? and also I couldnt understand the meaning if `{*}`?

Comment: You can tweak the value in order to change the vertical position of the text, it can even be negative number.
`{*}` is the argument that is responsible for an additional space in that column. You can try to put `20em`, for example to see what it does. When it is `*` width is calculated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions: either use the optional argument of `multirow` to take into account the rules padding added by `booktabs` or cheat with the number of lines in the first argument, by trial and error – you now can use a number of lines with a decimal part.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf},
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
     \multirow{2}{*}[-0.5\belowrulesep]{\textbf{Number}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Accuracy (\%)}}\\
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}} & {\textbf{BB}} & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule
    Number & AA & BB & CC\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \vskip 1cm
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
     \multirow{2.25}{*}{\textbf{Number}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Accuracy (\%)}}\\
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}} & {\textbf{BB}} & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule
    Number & AA & BB & CC\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]